# how to check if network discovery is on using powershell?

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, windows-server-2016, server-settings

I have just built a new server - `windows server 2016`

when trying to access its c: drive from any other server I was getting this error:

[image]

The I changed this settings:

[image]

and all is working fine.

question:

Is there a way to check if `network discovery` is `on` using `powershell`?

otherwise, when they give me another server, how can I check for this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not powershell, but:

Enable discovery:
`netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes`
Disable discovery:
`netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=No`

[link](https://tunecomp.net/all-methods-to-turn-on-network-discovery-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, but I don't think this answers the question about _how to check_.

Comment: `Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery" | ft`  (source: https://blog.frankfu.com.au/2018/03/13/enabling-network-discovery-on-windows-server/